# POST request in AJAX dont work asynchronous

Tags: javascript, ajax, post, asynchronous

I have a problem with an AJAX call that i make to login a user. The code looks like this:

```
function loginUser()
{
    var xmlhttp;
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }

    else {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            //alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
            var responseString = xmlhttp.responseText;
            if(responseString.indexOf("loginStatus:approved") != -1) {
                document.getElementById("logInBar").innerHTML = "Welcome " + getCookie("userLoggedOnfn") + " <a href=\"logoutUser.php\">Logout</a>";
            }
        }
    }

    var params = "loginUsername=" + document.getElementById("loginUsername").value +
                 "&loginPassword=" + document.getElementById("loginPassword").value +
                 "&d=" + new Date().getTime();

    //alert(params);

    xmlhttp.open("POST", "loginUser.php", true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
    xmlhttp.send(params);

        //alert("."); //this alert box is needed to make it work if it's asynchronous
}
```

The problem is that if i have it like this, it never reaches readyState == 4, or 3 for that matter... it only gets to 2. And if I break the js operations before it reaches readyState == 3 in the debugger in chrome, it gets to readyState == 4. And if I do it synchronous, it works, or if I add the alert box in the end... it's like it needs to pause before it can reach readyState == 4 or something... So what I'm i doing wrong?

Btw, i need to do this in pure AJAX because it's a school assignment...

Comment: Try it in Firefox, Chrome just doesn't like local AJAX.

Comment: I make local Ajax requests all the time in chrome, it's going to a local server, should work fine. Files, OTOH, not so much.

Comment: Have you verified the server is receiving the request?

Comment: Like i said. I get to readyState == 2, but not 3... and 2 is "request received" according to w3schools...

Comment: readystate 2 essentially means the browser got a TCP ACK, but no real response yet. Something is up with the server. you need to verify some other way that your sending the right message to the server.

Comment: It's my private webserver so maby it's my own fault... But what could be wrong? (the server is a Win7 based, apache 2.2 server with php and sql support)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem! It was in the html code.

I had the login button and text boxes inside a form tag, and chrome automatically refreshed the whole page when i pressed the button inside the form tag. So the AJAX call was messed up because of the reloading of the page.

I just removed the form tags and the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

it could be because of the `quotas` within + getCookie("userLoggedOnfn") + "; escape the `getCookie(\"userLoggedOnfn\")` and see it works

from console

```
   Refused to set unsafe header "Content-length"
   Refused to set unsafe header "Connection"
```